# PHP - Xampp reporting erros while hosting does not

Tags: php

Could someone explain me why when testing some PHP code on localhost warns with errors and uploading it on my hosting does not?

I find it disturbing, since is not the first time it happens, but seems like it works fine anyway...

Example:

Using a simple protect password in a single page:

```
<?php
// Define your username and password
$username = "logitek_00164";
$password = "JHvzQ3jK";

if ($_POST['txtUsername'] != $username || $_POST['txtPassword'] != $password) {

?>

<form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

<label for="txtUsername">Username:</label>

<input type="text" title="Enter your Username" name="txtUsername" />

<label for="txtpassword">Password:</label>

<input type="password" title="Enter your password" name="txtPassword" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Reports this error:  **Notice: Undefined index: txtUsername in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_password\index.php on line 6**

I know that reporting errors OFF could be a solution (the worst one), and in the other hand, I could solve the problem, but **I am just wondering if the problem comes by some PHP configuration or not.**

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because php in XAMPP is configured like that in php.ini and php on your server isn't.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

It can also be configured inside your php script.
See http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: depending on the configuration you set, errors and notice messages will/won't be generated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
if ((isset($_POST['txtUsername'])&&$_POST['txtUsername'] != $username )|| (isset($_POST['txtUsername'])&&$_POST['txtPassword'] != $password)) {
```

Well error reporting is also configured in `php.ini` you can disable(I wont recommend in development) from there.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but as you said, disabling it is not the best solution

Comment: Yes but writing an error free code could be one and also is considered as good practice.

Comment: Of course, as you said it should be error free code, but in the other hand, your code just breaks my website. 

Thank you anyway for your time, I really appreciate it